# How to watch/verify pod eviction call is complete with python client?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

Using the python client, I've written a function to evict all pods on a node. How can i monitor/watch for all pods to be fully evicted?

I'm using the create_namespaced_pod_eviction method to evict all pods on a single node. While this works, it doesn't wait for the process to finish before continuing. I need the eviction process 100% complete before moving on in my script. How can i monitor the status of this process? Similar to kubectl, i'd like my function to wait for each pod to evict before returning.

```py
# passes list of pods to evict function
def drain_node(self):
    print("Draining node", self._node_name)
    self.cordon_node()
    pods = self._get_pods()
    response = []
    for pod in pods:
      response.append(self._evict_pod(pod))
    return response

# calls the eviction api on each pod
def _evict_pod(self, pod, delete_options=None):
    name = pod.metadata.name
    namespace = pod.metadata.namespace
    body = client.V1beta1Eviction(metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=name, namespace=namespace))
    response = self._api.create_namespaced_pod_eviction(name, namespace, body)
    return response

# gets list of pods to evict
def _get_pods(self):
    all_pods = self._api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=True, field_selector='spec.nodeName=' + self._node_name)
    user_pods = [p for p in all_pods.items
                  if (p.metadata.namespace != 'kube-system')]
    return user_pods
```

Answer (score 2):

As given in this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#create_namespaced_pod_eviction), the `create_namespaced_pod_eviction` call returns [`V1Beta1Eviction`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1beta1Eviction.md) object. It has [`ObjectMeta`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ObjectMeta.md) object, that contains the `deletion_timestamp` field. Perhaps you can use that to determine if the pod is already deleted. Or probably polling the pod status might give the same ObjectMeta.